# Simulating a cellular automata using VIM mappings?

Tags: vim, text, language-agnostic, macros, cellular-automata

Having nothing better to do, I've learned that if you open the following text on vim:

```
...............X..........................................
...............X..........................................
................XX........................................
..................XX......................................
....................XX....................................
......................XXX.................................
.........................XXX..............................
............................XX............................
..............................XX..........................
................................XX........................
..................................X.......................
...................................X......................
...................................X......................
...................................X......................
..................................X.......................
................................XX........................
..............................XX..........................
............................XX............................
.........................XXX..............................
......................XXX.................................
....................XX....................................
..................XX......................................
................XX........................................
...............X..........................................
...............X..........................................
...............X..........................................
................XX........................................
..................XX......................................
....................XX....................................
......................XXX.................................
.........................XXX..............................
............................XX............................
..............................XX..........................
................................XX........................
..................................X.......................
...................................X......................
...................................X......................
...................................X......................
..................................X.......................
................................XX........................
..............................XX..........................
............................XX............................
.........................XXX..............................
......................XXX.................................
....................XX....................................
..................XX......................................
................XX........................................
...............X..........................................
```

... set the following map:

```
:noremap t ddGpgg
```

... and hold the "t" key down, you'll watch a cool sine waving.

This, on other hand:

```
:noremap t ddGpMddGpgg
```

Will candy your eyes with a cool DNA-spinning animation. What other neat looking animations are possible with VIM mappings? Is it possible to simulate a cellular automaton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linus Akesson's created some cool (somewhat related) things: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/vim/

Comment: Well that is a pretty good answer for a question I expected none.